# Magento 2 - Is there a way to add a custom help box next to product customizable attributes?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom, popup

On a product page, you can have customizable options, like:

---

[image]

---

There are probably people out there who don't know what "Finish" means. In this case, I'd like to add a `small help box`, maybe like this:

---

[image]

And when someone `hovers or clicks on it`, it'll `pop up` a tooltip.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it? Is there an `extension` out there that can do this easily?

Comment: Do you want to add tool tip for all  option or for specific option?

Comment: @RakeshVarma Specific options, but if multiple products have the same customizable option then the help box (with tooltip) will show

Comment: You have to install some third party extension or you can customise text.phtml file under product/view/options/type.. for text type custom option

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps given below.

Create the following file in your theme

> app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/options/type/select.phtml

```
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select */ ?>
<?php
$_option = $block->getOption();
$class = ($_option->getIsRequire()) ? ' required' : '';
?>
<div class="field<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>">
    <label class="label" for="select_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option->getId() ?>">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option->getTitle()) ?></span>
    </label>

    <?php 
        /**** custom tooltip starts ****/ 
        // add your option id in the if condition
    ?>
    <?php if ($_option->getId() == 2) : ?>
        <span class="custom-tooltip">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip-toggle">?</a>
            <span class="tooltip-content">Add your tooltip content here</span>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php /**** custom tooltip ends ****/ ?>

    <div class="control">
        <?= $block->getValuesHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()): ?>
            <?php if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO || $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX): ?>
                <span id="options-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option->getId() ?>-container"></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Create a less file

> app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/web/css/source/_extend.less

```
#product-options-wrapper .custom-tooltip {
    .lib-tooltip(right);
}

#product-options-wrapper .custom-tooltip a {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 7px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Run following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```